# Celery: How to separate the logic of Publisher and Consumer?

Tags: python, celery

I am new to Celery. In this [example](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#first-steps), I am unable to figure out how to separate the logic of publisher and consumer. Is the command `celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO` used to start working for publishing or consuming?

If `add.delay(4, 4)` is to push data into a queue, how do I connect to the same queue in a separate code file and consume it?

Answer (score 1):

Publishers are typically either Celery beat (scheduler), custom scripts that you develop, or other tasks executed by Celery workers in your cluster.

Consumers are EXCLUSIVELY Celery workers. Unless you dig really deep into Celery/Kombu and implement your own consumer you are pretty much not able to write consumer so easily.

Comment: So in order to consume I will always have to reply on a _Celery Worker_ and it i snot like Kafka to use a library to connect Celery server and consume data?

Comment: Your Celery tasks are what Celery runs to consume messages.